# Adding "onclick" attribute to asp.net dropdownlist item

Tags: asp.net, javascript

I can add an attribute to items in a RadioButtonList item like so:

```
PaymentMethodDropDownList.Items[0].Attributes.Add("onclick", "javascript:showNoMethods();");
PaymentMethodDropDownList.Items[1].Attributes.Add("onclick", "javascript:showCreditCardMethod();");
PaymentMethodDropDownList.Items[2].Attributes.Add("onclick", "javascript:showSendPaymentMethod();");
```

However, when I try to add the attributes to a DropDownList control it doesn't seem to work.  I would expect it to be similar.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This cannot be done in the same way as a radioButtonList, for a dropdownlist, the correct attribute event name is "onchange"  instead of "onclick".
The event should be attached to DropDownList Itself and not the items as follows:

```
PaymentMethodDropDownList.Attributes.Add("onchange",
                                            "showCreditCardMethod();");
```

Also, this is a little bit more complicated and requires a custom javascript function to perform a different action depending on the option selected. Here's an example:

```
PaymentMethodDropDownList.Attributes.Add("onchange",
                                             "handleDropDownEvents(this);");
```

**Custom Javascript function:** this assumes that values for the dropdown items are "CreditCard"  and "SendPayment".

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function handleDropDownEvents(e){
      if(e.value == "CreditCard"){
         showCreditCardMethod();
      }
      else if(e.value == "SendPayment"){
        showSendPaymentMethod();
      }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: It shouldn't be attached to the items, but to the list itself.

Comment: Is there a way I can attach it to the items like on a RadioButtonList?  That's what I'm trying to get at.

Comment: Yes, that was the work around I had been doing, but I thought I would check to see if I could handle it the same was I was with a RadioButtonList.  That's interesting that they are different.  Thank you.

Comment: The reason is because in a RadioButtonList, each item becomes an independent <input type="radio"> element and as such can handle its own events. The dropdownlist on the other handle is just one single html element with options underneath.

Comment: You don't need the "javascript:" pseudo-protocol. It is required only on "href" attribute of an anchor and strongly discouraged there too.

Answer (score 1):

Actualy for a DropDownList in ASP .Net, the property you're looking for is *OnSelectedIndexChanged* or *OnTextChanged* . Both does quite the same job.

Hope this help ;)

Comment: @Fox - those are the correct server side events. However, He is looking for the client side events.