# How to add client side OnClick actions to text in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, javascript, onclick

I'm generating a table of content in an ASP.NET page and I want to add client side `OnClick` actions to each cell (the action should be to set the value of a named TextBox control to the text in the clicked cell). If I could directly add stuff to the HTML output, I think I could do this with a single line of JavaScript in each cell.

Given that I'me **not** now using JQuery (and never have before), what is the simplest solution to adding this (including the time spent learning stuff)?

---

Edit: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/821341/adding-onclick-attribute-to-asp-net-dropdownlist-item) seems to work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are creating your table programmatically, using HtmlControls, you can set the onclick client attribute of the HtmlTableCell:

```
HtmlTableCell cell = new HtmlTableCell();
cell.Attributes.Add("onclick", "someFunction();");
```

However, if you're using jQuery you can do something like this:

```
$('td').click(function(){ // Select all the table cells on the document.
  $(this).html($('#textboxId').val()); // When clicked, change the innerHTML
});                                    // with a textbox value.
```

Answer (score 1):

You should give each cell a css class... class="contentsCell"

You can then add the following script to your head tag (along with a jquery include)

$(document).ready(function(){

```
$(".contentsCell").click(function(){
    CallYourFunction();
})
```

})

Where CallYourFunction() is you own function...

This will basically attach an

onclick=" CallYourFunction();"

to each td cell (or any other element) with the class "contentsCell"

Also, if you want to grab the text inside the cell, something like:

$(document).ready(function(){

```
$(".contentsCell").click(function(){
    var mytext = $(this).text();
    CallYourFunction(mytext);
});
```

});

Check out visualjquery.com for a great reference for jquery

Answer (score 1):

it depends how you're generating that table of content.

1. If bulding up using a table control, you can add JavaScript to [TableCell](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.tablecell.aspx) controls using the [Attributes.Add()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.webcontrol.attributes.aspx) method.
2. If building up with the GridView, you can add JavaScript when the [RowDataBound](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.rowdatabound.aspx) event is raised

Answer (score 0):

Well, your question is kind of difficult to follow, but I'll give you a few pointers.

Each control has a ClientID property. This is useful for injecting into your javascript so you know the client side id of the control.

jQuery syntax for putting text into a textbox would be like the following:

```
$("#" + clientId).attr("value", theValue);
```

and the jQuery syntax for getting text from a cell would be:

```
$("#" + cellId).html()
```